# JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I am working on json data.I convert csv file into json and when i try to validate that data through different json validator sites i get following error:

> JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate

My data is in following way:

```
[{
    "also_item": "item3",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item3",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item4",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item4",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item5",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item5",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item6",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item6",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item7",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item7",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item8",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item8",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item9",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item9",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item20",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item20",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item21",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item21",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item22",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item22",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item10",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item10",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item11",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item11",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item12",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item12",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item13",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item13",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item14",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item14",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item15",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item15",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item16",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item16",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item17",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item17",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item18",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item18",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item",
    "rank": "1"
}, {
    "also_item": "item19",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item19",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item1",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item1",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item2",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item2",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item3",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item3",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item4",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item4",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item5",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item5",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item6",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item6",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item7",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item7",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item8",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item8",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item9",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item9",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item20",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item20",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item21",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item21",
    "rank": "1"
}][{
    "also_item": "item22",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item22",
    "rank": "1"
}]
```

I am using [this](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer#) for validation.
Can anyone tell that how my json data should look like or what type of error it is.

Comment: Which validator exactly were you using? Please link it.

Comment: Looks pretty invalid to me - those are multiple JSON strings. You'd need an array where items are separated by commata.

Comment: Need a lot more information such as how you convert this, and why structure is so strange. Looks like you are doing something wrong in conversion process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a valid JSON.

If you paste your JSON into something like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ you should see your issue.

The structure isn't great. 
It should be an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "also_item": "item3",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item3",
    "rank": "1"
  },
  {
    "also_item": "item4",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item4",
    "rank": "1"
  }
]
```

**Edit**

@Downgoat is along the right lines, but you would have to wrap the entire result in an array `[]`. Then it would work, but I think you should address the structure. Having many arrays containing one object isn't good. You should have 1 array with many objects.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be between entries:

```
}][{
```

You need to have a comma between them:

```
}],[{
```

you also shouldn't have arrays surrounding just one object, the array should surround then entire JSON

---

Here's your fixed JSON:

```
[
    {
        "also_item": "item3",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item3",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item4",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item4",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item5",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item5",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item6",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item6",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item7",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item7",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item8",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item8",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item9",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item9",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item20",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item20",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item21",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item21",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item22",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item22",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item10",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item10",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item11",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item11",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item12",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item12",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item13",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item13",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item14",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item14",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item15",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item15",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item16",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item16",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item17",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item17",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item18",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item18",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item19",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item19",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item1",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item1",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item2",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item2",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item3",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item3",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item4",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item4",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item5",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item5",
        "rank": "1"
    }][{
        "also_item": "item6",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item6",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item7",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item7",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item8",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item8",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item9",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item9",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item20",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item20",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item21",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item21",
        "rank": "1"
    },
    {
        "also_item": "item22",
        "unit_count": "1",
        "driver": "item22",
        "rank": "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: @charlietfl see the second line: "you also shouldn't have arrays surrounding just one object, the array should surround then entire JSON"

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid because you have multiple root elements. You need to convert similar to the following example. You have extra "][" between item3 and item4 for example. Remove with a "," and it will work. Repeat the same for all others.

```
[{
    "also_item": "item3",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item3",
    "rank": "1"
},{
    "also_item": "item4",
    "unit_count": "1",
    "driver": "item4",
    "rank": "1"
}]
```